# What is the maximum wanted level in Assassin's Creed 4?

Tags: assassins-creed-4-black-flag

I've been playing Assassin's Creed 4 : Black Flag for a while now and the thought just hit me, what is the highest wanted level on the game? I'm aware that when you raid a ship your wanted level goes up if you choose not to lower it, but I was just wondering what the max level is, and what kind of hunters are chasing you by that point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maximum wanted level is level 4, which Prima quantifies as having picked up [210 penalty points or more](http://www.primagames.com/games/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag/guides/assassins-creed-iv-black-flag-eguide/reference-analysis/the-wanted-system) from attacking and sinking ships.

Once you reach wanted level 4, the hunter patrol waves will consist of a frigate and man o' war, levels 38 and 60 respectively. Even these are still fairly easy to take on with a fully upgraded Jackdaw, but they can make fairly decent additions to Kenway's Fleet if you play that side game.